# Using v-html with message data -- does Vue not support the <title> element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, accessibility

I am using Vue.js 2, my SDK is IntelliJ:

I am trying to import HTML into a Vue.js file.

The purpose is for the `<title></title>` attribute,  since Vue doesn't directly seem to support this.

In the `<template>` markup, I have:

```
div v-html="message1"></div>
```

In the data, I have a very simple message1:

> ```
> message1:   '<title>My webpage -- from message1 </title>',
> ```

Interestingly, I can display message1 with "moustache" syntax, but it just shows the title tags.

The message1 used by v-html compiles, but it doesn't appear on the page as rendered.

Is the premise that Vue doesn't directly support `<title></title>` correct?  I've seen complex workarounds for this, but is there a simple HTML-like way of getting this tag there for simple static text? The goal of this is for accessibility purposes.

The actual goal is to get it to display in the "tab" part of the page, where it should display. I can display it on the page, but not in the "tab" part of the page (above the URL on most browsers).

Comment: Why are you trying to display the `<title>` element in the first place? Semantically that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It really needs to go to the "tab" part of the page, where it should display.  I can display it on the page, but not in the "tab" part of the page [above the URL on most browsers].

Comment: See also this web-page:  https://medium.com/@Taha_Shashtari/the-easy-way-to-change-page-title-in-vue-6caf05006863  It has a very complete mixin-method for changing the tab of web-page and it does work for vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp), many browsers have a default css style for the `title` tag.

In Chrome there is:

```css
title {
  display: none;
}
```

You should use another tag or just override the default style.

Comment: Basically, my purpose is to use the <title></title> tagging.  This is in my requirements for my accessibility task.  So, is there a way to override the default style, please?

Comment: Yes, just add the rule `title {display: block}` in your css file or within a `style` tag

Comment: Two comments, both favorable to Fab:  i) other tags would work, such as <span>, but they are not in my requirements.  ii) Adding the {display: block}  is also working, so I accepted answer.

Comment: Note: although my .vue page references a stylesheet with title defined, I cannot alter that stylesheet, so I added this to the top of my file (If anyone googles this and needs to do it):  <style>title {display: block;   color:#2c4557;font-size: 48pt; margin:10px 0;} </style>

Comment: See also this web-page:  https://medium.com/@Taha_Shashtari/the-easy-way-to-change-page-title-in-vue-6caf05006863  It has a very complete mixin-method for changing the tab of web-page and it does work for vue.